# Need help figuring out what is wrong with my code

Tags: sql

1. I want a result set that will show me the invoices grouped by the vendor.
2. I want a result set that will show me the vendors and the total amount they have been invoiced in order from least amount invoiced to most amount invoiced.
3. I want a result set that shows the vendors and the total amount they have been invoiced that have a total amount greater than $2000.00.

```
Select * from Invoices group by VendorID;

Select Vendors.VendorID,Vendors.VendorName,sum(Invoices.InvoiceTotal) 
from Vendors inner join Invoices on Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID group by Vendors.VendorID order by sum(Invoices.InvoiceTotal);


Select Vendors.VendorID,Vendors.VendorName,sum(Invoices.InvoiceTotal) 
from Vendors inner join Invoices on Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID group by Vendors.VendorID having sum(Invoices.InvoiceTotal) > 2000;
```

This code gives me the same error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Column 'Invoices.InvoiceID' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> Column 'Vendors.VendorName' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>
> Column 'Vendors.VendorName' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far to solve this. Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please edit your question and give it a meaningful title. Everybody who asks a question here _Need help figuring out what is wrong with my code_

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a subquery of the join

```
Select * from 
(Select Vendors.VendorID, Vendors.VendorName, sum(Invoices.InvoiceTotal) as total 
from Vendors inner join Invoices on Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID) 
as T1 group by T1.VendorID order by T1.total;
```

Answer (score 0):

#1: For me *grouped by the vendor* might mean `order by vendorID` or more probable a simple `COUNT`.

#2&3: You have to add `Vendors.VendorName` to the `GROUP BY` list